# Extract Keepass password generator dictionary

Tags: passwords, keepass

Can I extract a dictionary list from the keepass password generator as my senior forgot his master password?

Comment: What "dictionary list" are you talking about? Do you want the passwords from the *random password generator*, or do you want to recover the *saved* passwords? Either way, there is no process to get what you want. It, and all other password vaults, are designed to prevent access without the master password...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Theres a keypass exploit that allows to extract a big part of the master PW from a dump

Answer (score 2):

The Keepass password generator is [well documented](https://keepass.info/help/base/pwgenerator.html). And it approaches the ideal of a password generator in that knowledge of the scheme used to generate the password doesn't make it meaningfully weaker.

If you are genuinely acting on behalf of someone who forgot their master password, then your best bet is to work with them to help recover from them everything and anything about it that they do remember. If they remember enough information sufficiently narrow down the set of possible passwords, then you could try to feed that information into a cracking tool (or hire experts on the use of such tools.) If however you do not have the cooperation of the person whose master password you are seeking, then just go ahead and try to brute force all possible Keepass generated passwords. Please give us a progress report on that attempt every 10 million years or so.

Answer (score 1):

There's no such list.

Keepass generates random passwords when you request it to. There's no pattern, and keepass authors are quite focused on security, so it's unlikely that they use low quality randomness.

Such a list would be a terrible back door.